# LINQ Group by column name passed as parameter - LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2015, linq-to-sql

Consider the LINQ code :

```
 var objs = (ClientsDB.Context.ClientProcessed.GroupBy(grp => new
            {
                City = grp.City,
                Day = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Day,
                Month = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Month,
                Year = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Year
            })....



var objs = (ClientsDB.Context.ClientProcessed.GroupBy(grp => new
        {
            Department = grp.Department,
            Day = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Day,
            Month = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Month,
            Year = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Year
        })....


var objs = (ClientsDB.Context.ClientProcessed.GroupBy(grp => new
{
    State = grp.State,
    Day = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Day,
    Month = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Month,
    Year = grp.Insert_Date.Value.Year
})....
```

How can I have GroupBy done by a specific column passed as a string ?

For example :

```
String grpByParam = "City"; // grpByParam = "State"; // String grpByParam = "Department";
```

And then pass that param to a linq query , instead of duplicating LINQ queries every now and again .

FYI , I need that as LINQ-TO-SQL and not LINQ-TO-OBJECTS query , meaning I want the filtering to be done in the DB , and not in the memory .

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: So you are grouping by 4 columns in your example. What would be the string representing that group by condition?

Comment: @Evk : String grpByParam = "City"; // grpByParam = "State"; // grpByParam = "Department";

Comment: I believe it is possible, but I doubt it will worth it. You can generate anonymous type and expression which creates instance of anonymous type dynamicaly, but you can't use it in plain c# code, you'll have to generate Func, which invokes GroupBy with that dynamic expression. Here is the sample of type and expression generation I found in the internet https://gist.github.com/dcastro/9093000. If you create type for each possible query, that's not so cool.

Comment: You don't need a string. The `GroupBy` key argument can be any lambda function that matches the `Func<TSource,TKey>` signature. You can construct different lambdas based on a condition or even pass the lambda itself as a `Func<TSource,TKey>` argument

Answer (score 0):

You can check the string value and call `GroupBy` based on that

```
if (grpByParam.Equals("City")) {
    result = source.GroupBy(a => a.City);
} ...
```

You can implement a method which takes a `source` (the LINQ query without the `GroupBy`) and `return` a `result` (the result of `GroupBy`)

See

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its
>   GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For
>   Each in Visual Basic.

in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).